# Variables in AWS ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am currently trying out serverless for AWS lambda and I am currently stuck in the policy side in order to serverless to be able to deploy. I've search around what are the necessary policies needed and I've found this particular policy

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudformation:CreateStack",
        "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
        "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/${project}*"
}
```

I am new to aws policies and I am curious about the `$(project)` part. I assume that would be an variable. My question is where is that variable defined?

Comment: Where did you find this?  In context, I would assume that `${project}` is not a genuine variable, but rather a placeholder, like saying "insert-your-project-name-here."  I know I tend to use that convention when documenting things, e.g. if I wrote something like `https://s3.${region}.amazonaws.com`, that would have the same intention as if I had written  `https://s3.REGION-GOES-HERE.amazonaws.com`... just cleaner and more refined.  (Also, I could be wrong.  Please provide a link.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, **${project}** was intended as a placeholder which represents a specific CloudFormation stack name you will need to provide by either hard-coding a static stack name or hard-coding a stack name with a wildcard in it.

`"Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/foo"`

`"Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/foo*"`

The first example is just a static stack name called **foo** and will only grant your Lambda permissions over a CloudFormation stack **with that exact name**.

The second example represents any stack name that begins with **foo** and optionally ends with something else, such as **foo-05**, **foobar**, **foo-tastic** or just plain **foo**. Wildcarding gives your Lambda more flexibility with what Cloudformation stacks it has permissions for.

IAM policies support pre-defined variables such as **${aws:username}**, **${aws:CurrentTime}**, and **${aws:SourceIp}**, but they do not custom variables like **$(project}**. Whomever wrote that example policy should have represented the stack name as  or something, so to avoid confusion like this.

A little extra bit of info:

If you want to dive deeper, there are in fact ways you can parameterize IAM policies with custom variables, but this requires you to deploy your IAM policies with AWS CloudFormation or with third-party tools such as Ansible. These methods are much more sophisticated and are essential if you wish to automate your deployments.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse